# Issue using imagecreatefromjpeg() to upload jpg Image file

Tags: php, jpeg

When I try to use imagecreatefromjpeg() on certain jpg files from my phone onto my site, I get some that have issues with validating they are actual jpg images.

The errors I get when I tried:

```
PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): &quot;/tmp/phpBGoiQg&quot; is not a valid JPEG file
```

From what I've been able to figure out on my own so far is that the big difference on some of the ones that error out are that these photos are from Instagram after you edit them, and this issue has to do something with either the meta data, encoding, or compression. If I edit them on my phone and save the image again, it uploads just fine, but that's where the problem lies.

I can't find a real solution on how to fix this so my users don't have to worry about editing their photos in order to upload them. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd happy to figure out what I can on my own.

For now I've setup a check to just notify the users that the specific photo(s) were skipped. But I really want to be able to fix them, somehow?

```
if (exif_imagetype($file_temp_name) === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
//do resize, else skip and report issue.
}
```

**UPDATE**

So after working on this and figuring out the jpg does seem to be a jpg2000 image due to the hexadecimal being 00 00 00 starting off, I've been trying to figure out how to work with this via the php upload.

I've tried some imagick stuff, like exec() function to try to convert the image, and also trying to resave as a different format. No luck.

I'm not sure where to go from here because I can't find any similar situations like this. Maybe I'm bad at googling, but I really would appreciate any pointers.

Code Snippet:

```
case 'image/jpeg': //case 'image/pjpeg':
if (exif_imagetype($file_temp_name) === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_temp_name);
} else {
    // Check for the JPEG 2000 magic number (00 00 00)
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file_temp_name);
    if (substr($fileContents, 0, 3) === "\x00\x00\x00") {
        $uploadedFile = $file_temp_name;
        $outputFilename = "NEW-$file_name";

        if (file_exists($uploadedFile)) {
            $command = "convert $uploadedFile $outputFilename";
            exec($command);

            if (file_exists($outputFilename)) {
                $_report .= "Image conversion successful! ";

                $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($outputFilename);
            } else {
                $_report .= "Image conversion failed. [$uploadedFile to $outputFilename] ";

                exec($command, $output, $returnCode);
                $_report .= "Error: " . implode("\n", $output); // Log the error messages
            }
        } else {
            $_report .= "Image doesn't exist. [$uploadedFile to $outputFilename] ";
        }
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: What does `exif_imagetype` actually return for those images - just false?

Comment: Can you open such images with an image editor?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the offending jpeg and give more info about the device it was created with and possible software is has been through?

Comment: @CBroe yeah it returns false, and if I remove that condition, that's when the imagecreate gives the error.

Comment: @Olivier yeah it functions, loads, and edits like a normal image.

Comment: @Jos yeah I'll try to do that today, but if I recall, I'll need to upload it to a place that won't re-save it entirely as a new image.

Comment: Update: Emailing them to myself let me upload them with no issues. But I checked out the hexadecimal on the post from Alvaro Gonzalez and it does look like it's a jpeg 2000 image. Going to investigate more.

Comment: If it's a JPEG 2000, then `exif_imagetype()` should return `IMAGETYPE_JP2`, not false...

Comment: @Olivier you see where my problem lies then, no? lol

Answer (score 1):

The [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) for JPEG files some programs use in order to identify them starts with `FF D8 FF`. You can verify that if you open a JPEG file with an [hexadecimal editor](https://hexed.it/). If your file really starts with `00 00` (it's worth checking) it's either corrupted or not a JPEG picture at all. It may be a [JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) file which, despite the name, is actually a different format:

```
00 00 00 0C 6A 50 20 20 0D 0A 87 0A
```

It's worth noting that some proxies automagically re-encode original files in different formats (e.g. webp) to save bandwidth but keep the original name, so you end up with a file called `foo.jpg` that's actually not a JPEG at all.

Comment: Question, and forgive my ignorance. Would that mean the error "JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00" is pointing to that, or are the error codes on the end something else? Just curious/learning more about this. 

I'll look more into jpeg 2000 file type, though. And try the hexadecimal editor, too.

Comment: It does look like it's a JPEG 2000 image. First 3 were 00 00 00

Comment: What does `exif_imagetype()` return exactly? Don't get confused by the name, JPEG2000 is just a different format like GIF or PNG, they only gave it that name because it was created by the same team, it was based on similar ideas and they wanted to create some confusion to ease adoption. `imagecreatefromjpeg()` is never going to work because it is NOT a JPEG. Formats that PHP support as listed at [imagecreatefromstring()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php). If you need something different, you'll have to use ImageMagick or something like that.

Comment: It returns blank, actually... Tried using it like this. 

$_report .= "Invalid or corrupted image type (".exif_imagetype($file_temp_name)."). "; and it was empty.

Comment: You get a blank because you cast `false` to string. `false` [means](https://php.net/exif_imagetype) that it didn't find a known signature. File is corrupted or not a supported picture format.

Comment: @DTSolutions *"First 3 were 00 00 00"* What's the forth? Is it 0C?

Comment: @Olivier 00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70 is the first row.

Comment: @DTSolutions Then this is not a JPEG 2000.

Comment: @DTSolutions 66 74 79 70 is the signature of [HEIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) format.